# How do I changed 503 error page in okd 4(router, haproxy)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, okd

I want to change the default error page in okd.

I replaced the /var/lib/haproxy/conf/error-page-503.http file of router-default with configmap, but it is automatically recovered as an error.

Thank you.

```
# oc edit deploy router-default
-------------------------------------------------------------------
...
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/haproxy/conf/error-page-503.http
          name: haproxy-custom-configs
          readOnly: true
          subPath: error-page-503.http
...
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 644
          items:
          - key: error-page-503.http
            path: error-page-503.http
          name: haproxy-custom-configs-error-page
        name: haproxy-custom-configs-error-page
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Gdeployment.apps/router-default edited

### Error Events
router-default-7c756d885-bd27l - NamespaceNSopenshift-ingress

0/9 nodes are available: 2 node(s) had taint {infra: reserved}, that the pod didn't tolerate, 3 node(s) didn't match node selector, 4 node(s) didn't match pod affinity/anti-affinity, 4 node(s) didn't match pod anti-affinity rules.
```